# I'm so confused about inverse Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm confused about inverse Laplace transform.
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-c-i\infty}^{-c+i\infty}f(s)e^{st}ds$$
Which one is this integral inverse of, normal Laplace transform or two sided Laplace transform (I mean, the one whose integral interval is from $-\infty$ to $\infty$)?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not demonstrate minimal prior research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Laplace transform of a function $f$ is
\begin{equation}
  \mathcal{L}(f)(s)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-s t}f(s)dt.
\end{equation}

The inverse Fourier transform is
\begin{equation}
  \mathcal{L}^{-1}(F)(s)=\int_{-c-i\infty}^{-c+i\infty} e^{st}F(t)dt
\end{equation}
where $c$ is a real number so that the contour path of integration is in the region of convergence of $F(s)$.

Comment: So you mean that complex integral is inverse of lapalce transform whose interval is from -$\infty$ to $\infty$?

Comment: Oh I just have known that inverse of L{f}(s) and inverse of B{f}(s) is the same